# Mouse moved events during button mouse up event

Tags: swift, cocoa

I want to receive information about mouse move events during button click (mouse up)

I'm adding `NSTrackingArea` to view that I want to track mouse move and mouse dragged events on, but I still don't receive these events.

I assume that `mouseDown` in `NSButton` is blocking mouse events, so the only solution I come up with is overriding `mouseDown` function for `NSButton` and not calling `super.mouseDown`, but then I need to handle button selection manually and I'm not sure if this is right approach for this.

Is this a right solution for my problem? Will there be no problems? Is there a better solution?

Here is code for test, just add button to new project and assign `TestButton` class to it.

```
class TestButton: NSButton {

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("Mouse up")
        super.mouseDown(with: event) // After removing events works.
        print("Mouse down")
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: view.bounds, options: [.activeAlways, .mouseMoved, .enabledDuringMouseDrag], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("Mouse moved")
        super.mouseMoved(with: event)
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("Mouse dragged")
        super.mouseDragged(with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: `view.window` property will always be `nil` inside `viewDidLoad` method, therefore using optional biding to set `acceptsMouseMovedEvents`  to `true` will fail silently. You need to set this property inside `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` method where `view.window` it is NOT `nil`

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I removed this line since it does not change anything

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement for my project. So initially, I started out with NSButton just like you. But, it turned out to be more hectic than I thought. Handling the action and selected state where the main concerns I faced. You could proceed with NSButton if it actually meets up with your requirement. But, I eventually moved to NSView and customised it. So, few of my implementation for handling move and drag event implementation I've open-sourced [here](https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/MacOS_AppKit_Cocoa_Draggable_Resizable_NSView) is the link.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to do this is to use a custom subclass of `NSButtonCell` and override [`continueTracking(last:current:in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscell/1535599-continuetracking) (inherited from `NSCell`). Your override should generally call through to `super` and return what it returns, but you can do something else in addition, to respond to the mouse movements. The issue is that `NSCell` and its subclasses have been "soft deprecated" for a while.

That said, it would be very surprising to me as a user that anything other than the button would react to the mouse movements while I'm interacting with the button (clicked in it and dragging).